# Need help putting image on bottom left of box DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to put another image on this page on the bottom right with text on the left. There is already an image on the top left with text on the right. Also, is it possible for the text to be vertically centered with the image? I know this looks sloppy, but it is my first time coding a website.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>   
<style>
  h1{
       color:white;
       font-size: 50px;
       font-family: ultra;
    }

    p{
    color:white;
    }

    h2{
    color:white;
    }

    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: red;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
        color: #818181;
   }

    .main {
        margin-left: 250px; 
        font-size: 28px; 
    }

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
body {  
    background-color:#252525;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    background-color: #252525;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
.rcorners1 {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    }

    .main img {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .main img{
    float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
<a href="home.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About</a>
<a href="Why Us.html">Why Us?</a>
<a href="Meet The Team.html">Meet The Team</a>
<a href="Gear.html">Gear</a>
<a href="Services.html">Services</a>
<a href="Products.html">Products</a>
<a href="Satisfied Customers.html">Reviews</a>
<a href="Location.html">Location</a>
<a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <h1>GEAR</h1>
</div>
<div align="center">
<div class="main">
    <div class="rcorners1" style="background-color: #fffafa;" "text-align:right;"> 
    <img src="Our Gadgets.jpg" class="expand" width="40%" height="50%" alt=""/> 
    <div class="text">The proton pack, designed by Dr. Egon Spengler, is a man-portable particle accelerator system that is used to create a charged particle beam composed of protons that is fired by the proton gun (also referred to as the "neutrona wand"). Described as a "positron collider", it functions by colliding high-energy positrons to generate its proton beam. The beam allows a Ghostbuster to contain and hold "negatively charged ectoplasmic entities". This containment ability allows the wielder to position a ghost above a trap for capture.</div>
    <img style="float: right;" src=" class="expand" width="40%" height="50%" alt=""/>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What tools are you using to write this code? If you are using notepad or another text editor you are missing out on feedback that other tools could offer as you are writing your HTML and CSS. If you don't want to switch to using an IDE you could copy and paste your CSS into an online [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and read through the feedback it gives you. There are similar tools for validating HTML which might suggest that you are missing elements like `<head>` and `<title>` and you could search to learn about those tags and how to use them.

Comment: I used to use notepad but I switched to Adobe Dreamweaver recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled with your code a bit and this is what I think you want to accomplish.
https://codepen.io/carmona-joel/pen/geNJmM

You need to define a class for each image.

```
img.img-1{
  float:left;
}
img.img-2{
  float:right;
}
```

or you can define it inline.

Yes you can center the image and the text.

Use

```
margin:0 auto;
/*for the img*/
```

and

```
text-align:center;
/*for text*/
```

Comment: Great but I still can't figure out how to get the text to be vertically centered to the picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler to solve than you might think. To have multiple elements in one line, it is recommended that you use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`. Typically you would have elements with a `display: block;` When it is a block, it gives most elements a new line, so there is only one per line. There are many exceptions that come as suprises. Also, not all elements are blocks. For example, the `<span>` element has no styling effect on the document, unless you give an id, name, class, or use javascript to style it. But back to your question, here is what I came up with.

```css
#im1 {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
}

#text1 {
float: right;
margin: 0px;
display: inline;
}

#im2 {
float: right;
margin: 0px;
display: inline;
}

#text2 {
float: left;
margin: 0px;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Here is where you would link your css to your document, or you could just use <style> but it is much easier to use a seperate document. You can find tutorials on w3schools on how to do this easily-->

<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<img id="img1" width="25%" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

<span id="text1">Oh, here is the text I was speaking of</span>
<br><br>
<img id="img2" width="25%" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
<span id="text2">Is this more text?</span>


</body>
</html>
```

What is happening here is that I am making the margin 0 pixels. That is overkill and not necessary because we made them inline elements, but I like to include it :). The margin is the amount of space around an element. I also make the elements float a certain direction, left or right. There are only left and right directions when using float. All it does is push it as far as it can to that direction without interupting other elements. Unless they are on different levels, which can be done with z-indexing(look on w3schools).

**Don't worry about this being your first time, everyone was a beginner at some point. Keep going and keep learning, there is so much more than websites to learn to make.**